# DB2: Retrieving latest order for every customer in a given table?

Tags: sql, db2

I have Customer and Order tables in DB2, I want a select query to retrieve the latest order details for each customer in the table.

so the query would return all the customers in the Customer table and the details of of the latest order (lets say order_id) placed by the customer(Customer can have many orders), Any ideas on the best way to go about this?

The Order table has a timestamp column with the time that an order was placed.

Something like this:

```
SELECT customer.name, order.order_id
FROM customer, order
WHERE customer.customer_id=order.customer_id
AND order.ordertime is newest
```

Many Thanks.

UPDATE: Just to make my question a little clearer, I would like a single row returned for each customer with the details of the latest order(single order) for that customer.

Comment: You should add info what qualifies the "latest" order (DateTime column, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, there is a timestamp column in the orders table.

Comment: Everyone keeps trying to give him a query that will just tell him the most recent order dates.  The goal, as the post states, is to get the *details* from the most recent orders.

Comment: @Sean I forgot to include the customer name at first on my answer, but it's updated with that now...

Answer (score 2):

First group by customer and select max order date:

```
select   customer_id, max(ordertime)
from     order
group by customer_id
```

You can't get all the other fields back with a query this simple though.  You'll need to join those results back to the order table again now to get what you want.

```
select  c.name, o.*
from    customer c join 
        order o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id join
(
    select   customer_id, max(ordertime) ordertime
    from     order
    group by customer_id
) RecentOrders on o.customer_id = RecentOrders.customer_id and 
                  o.ordertime = RecentOrders.ordertime
```

Comment: instead of using a select to create the table, i would put that query in a `WITH`.

Comment: @phanneman He's not using SQL Server.  I doubt db2 supports CTEs, otherwise that would be a good suggestion.

Comment: DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows has supported common table expressions since V5, which was released in 1998!

Answer (score 0):

can be solved using join
Customer_id is the primary key in customer table and is used in order table to recognize the customer who places the order.
Date is the column which has the date at which the order was place
(if you could provide the table structure i could write the right query for your structure)

```
SELECT customer_id,order_id
FROM (
Select o.customer_id,o.order_id,max(o.order_date)
FROM Customer c
inner join Orders o
ON o.customer_id=c.customer_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id,o.order_id
 )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this query return ALL orders; not only the latest order of each customer?

Comment: Would this query return a single row for every customer regardless of the amount of orders they have, or several rows depending on the amount of orders associated to the customer?

Comment: fetch first 1 would give you only one row

Comment: would this fetch the first row for each customer or the first row for the entire query?

Comment: Im looking for 1 row per customer. so for every single customer in the  customer table, the query returns a row for that customer with the details of the latest order placed by that customer.

Comment: Are you used to writing queries for MySQL?  This isn't valid SQL syntax for DB2, or any other RDBMS I'm aware of (except MySQL) - you either need to put every column in the `GROUP BY`, or add it to an aggregate function.  And even in MySQL, the non-aggregate columns have _random_ (more or less) results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works in MySQL, not sure about the syntactic differences between MySQL and DB2 :(

```
select c.name, s.* from (
    select o1.customer_id, o1.order_id from order o1
    left join order o2
    on o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id and o1.ordertime < o2.ordertime
    where o2.customer_id is null
) as S
join customers c on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
```

Comment: Say a customer has 3 orders.  One on the 1st, one on the 2nd, and one on the 3rd.  The one on the third will be greater than the the one on the 1st and 2nd, and the one on the 2nd will be greater than the one on the first, and you will end up with three records for that one customer.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about your query, but that's what it looks like to me at first glance anyway...

Comment: Take a better look :) There is a where clause you're missing. Think of when o2.customer_id will be null

Comment: Don't use implicit-join syntax, it's considered an antipattern.  Other than that, DB2 has an `EXCEPTION JOIN` which is the equivalent of the `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL` bit.  Otherwise, I think this should work.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yeah, I noticed the where after the first comment hence the second comment of self doubt.  It'll work, but besides what X-Zero just pointed out (and the fact that this may be difficult to understand when the next person comes to look at it) you are only returning the order date and not all the details of the order.  You might consider changing s.order_id to s.*

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT Customer1.Name, Order1.order_id
    FROM Customer Customer1, Order Order1 
    WHERE Customer1.customer_id = Order1.customer_id 
    AND Order1.LASTUPDATETIME = (
        SELECT MAX(Order2.LASTUPDATETIME)
            FROM Order Order2 
            WHERE Order2.customer_id=Order1.customer_id
        )
```

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan of this solution?  This looks closer to a cursor based approach in that it's running a subquery for every single customer.  At least, I think that because the where condition of the subquery keeps changing it would have to.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong about that though...